# Best practise for data binding a list in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am having trouble understanding the databinding in my Eclipse RCP application. I just can't figure out how it's supposed to work..

**Here's what I want to do**

I have a View where a list of texts should be displayed. The texts are "stored" in a simple `List<String>` which is provided via a singleton (for demonstration purpose only ;)). So whoever uses the `ListProvider` will get the list of texts. When the list changes I want my View to automatically update the table contents.

**Here's what I've done so far**

My List provider is an `Observable` that will notify observers when the list changes.

In my view I create an Observer to watch the list provider and when the observer is notified I refresh my view.

Code for the `ListProvider`:

```
public class ListProvider extends Observable {

    private Stack<String> hist;
    private static ListProvider instance;

    // Singleton implementation
    public static ListProvidergetInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new ListProvider
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void add(String text) {
        if (this.hist.size() == MAX_SIZE) {
            this.hist.remove(MAX_SIZE-1);
        }
        this.hist.add(0, text);
        // notify all observers
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Code for the view:

```
public class TestView extends ViewPart {

private TableViewer viewer;

[...]

class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
    public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    }
    public void dispose() {
    }
    public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
        return ClipboardHistory.getInstance().getList().toArray();
    }
}

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    IContentProvider contentProvider = new ViewContentProvider();
    viewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
    viewer.setInput(getViewSite());
    
    Observer listObserver = new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            // update the table viewer
            viewer.refresh();
        }
    };
    
    ListProvider.getInstance().addObserver(listObserver);
}
}
```

**Question**

Is using `Observer` and `Observable` the "right" way to go or am I missing something? I am not sure I've grasped the concept of RCP Databinding...

Comment: I am not sure about the scope of the items in your list but have you considered adding a simple SWT List (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FList.html) object to your view instead of a tableviewer etc etc

Comment: Also it might be better to use a ListViewer(http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FListViewer.html) instead of a TableViewer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. At the moment it's only a list but I want to add more data to other columns later. Would using a ListViewer change the way I observe the list?

Comment: If you will need multiple columns then you will need a TableViewer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you reading [JFace Databinding](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) and make use of `ViewerSupport`, `ObservableListContentProvider` and `BeanProperties` to simplfy the job.

You can also see a working example [JFace Databinding Snippet: Model to TableViewer binding](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet009TableViewer.java) for a reference, where the binding is done at last with the help of `ViewerSupport`:

```
(...)
TableViewer peopleViewer = new TableViewer(committers);
ViewerSupport.bind(peopleViewer, new WritableList(viewModel.getPeople(),
     Person.class), BeanProperties.value(Person.class, "name"));
```

With those helpers you won't need to implement the `Observer` for your list, and if you want your viewer to update its labels when data is modified take a look in the same example to `PropertyChangeSupport`, which allows you to refresh the viewer on every change on any element of the list that you notify through it. It's important that you use `BeanProperties` for the binding.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. But is there some way to use validators and converters with a table viewer using this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach with one possible exception. You need to make sure that the viewer is refreshed in the UI thread:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewer.refresh();
    }
});
```

However there are things that you can do to make the table update more efficient. In your code above it appears to only add a single item at the top of the table, so you'd be better with a call to:

```
viewer.insert( text, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the note on the UI thread.
As for the optimization with `viewer.insert` I don't think it's more efficient. I can't be sure what changes were made to my model. So I would have to check for updates/inserts/deletions. That's way more expensive than just getting the whole list again and display it. ;)